# How to upload a file in just one click 

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets

I have HTML page, which gives an option to upload a file to the server, there is a servlet action class at server side & it handles request and write the file. ***Here how it works***

1. Click to Browse the file and select the file
2. click the submit button.

But I want to upload in just one click on any button, please take a look of my code and suggest how to do that using javascript/jQuery fn.

```
<html> <head>  
  <script type = "text/javascript">
      function test() {
         var uploadfile = document.getElementByID("upload_id");
        uploadfile.click();  // here i can browse the file without clicking on file brows button
} </script>  </head> <body>

  <input type="button" id="just_one_click" value ="click me" onclick="test();" />

 <form action="upload.do" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <input type="file" id="upload_id" name = "fileupload" />
   <input type = "submit" value="upload" />

 </form>  </body> </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign id (let's say 'myform') to your form and use `document.getElementById('myform').submit();` instead of `uploadfile.click();`.

Comment: no it's not working. It directly invokes submit button while firstly file browse should invoke, Once you select file from file dialog then submit button should clicked/invoked.

Comment: ahh, I had not completely understand what you wanted. Now I've got it. So you want to upload immediately after file dialog closes, don't you? If so try code `document.getElementById('upload_id').onchange = function(){document.getElementById('myform').submit()};`

Comment: great.... Thank you so much :) it worked now          document.getElementByID("upload_id").click();
document.getElementById('upload_id').onchange = function(){document.getElementById('myform').submit()};